# How can i add numbers to a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, int, addition, var

I have been trying to do a simple game where you try to get the right number as the random number. If you win, you get 1 point. But I wasn't able to give that point. Here is what i have done :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Luck Game</title>
    <script>
    function onClick(){
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        var usernumber = document.getElementById("input").value ;
        var points = 0;
        document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = number ;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Points in your account : " + points;
        if(usernumber == number){
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "You WON !. You got 1 point added to your account !";
points = points + 1;

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "Ow, no luck, you lost..."
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input"></input>
    <p id="Answer"></p>
    <button onClick="onClick()"></button>
    <p id="WIN?"></p>
    <p id="points"></p>
</body>
```

But the "points = points + 1" is not working !
what is wrong ? please help me .

Comment: you must ensure `point` is treated as a number, `points = parseInt(points )+ 1;`

Comment: That, and don't reset the point value on each click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare your `var points` outside click function. E.g :

```
<script>
var points = 0;
    function onClick(){
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        var usernumber = document.getElementById("input").value ;

        document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = number ;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Points in your account : " + points;
        if(usernumber == number){
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "You WON !. You got 1 point added to your account !";
points = points + 1;

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "Ow, no luck, you lost..."
        }

    }
    </script>
```

So the counter will be saved somewhere else without being resetted everytime function procs.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written it, `points` is a variable local to the `onClick()` function so it will get reset to zero each time the function is called. If you pull the initialization of `points` out of `onClick()` then you will be able to safely increment its value:

```
<script>
    var points = 0;
    function onClick(){
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        var usernumber = document.getElementById("input").value ;

        document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = number ;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Points in your account : " + points;
        if(usernumber == number){
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "You WON !. You got 1 point added to your account !";
            points++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("WIN?").innerHTML = "Ow, no luck, you lost..."
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `var` points outside function:

```
var points = 0;

function onClick(){
    ...
}
```